# Chrome Android remote debugging - different behaviour when running script line separately

Tags: javascript, android, remote-debugging

I'm trying to run javascript code in order to debug chrome on android device via desktop with remote debugging.

When trying to run the following code:

```
var window1 = window.open('http://www.google.com'); 
var window2 = window.open('http://www.wikipedia.com'); 
window1.focus();
```

two new tabs open and the focus function doesn't seem to execute (the expected window doesn't become the front tab).

But when i run:

```
var window1 = window.open('http://www.google.com'); 
var window2 = window.open('http://www.wikipedia.com');
```

and

```
window1.focus();
```

as two separate scripts in the console, the tab does gain focus...

Why?